# TypeScript resolution of relative JS file import vs. Chrome resolution of import

Tags: typescript

My ASP.NET Core project is laid out like this.

```
/
/ts/Module.ts
/ts/OtherModule.ts
/node_modules/moment/moment.js
/wwwroot/lib/moment/moment.js
/wwwroot/js/Module.js
/wwwroot/js/OtherModule.js
```

Module.ts has an import like so:

```
import * as moment from "./cannot-get-this-to-work.js";
import * as other from "./OtherModule.js";
```

Since TypeScript does not rewrite those paths at compile time, they must be correct relative paths for Chrome to build the URL to get them. This works for my own modules which are all side-by-side.

But for other modules, I have them in `/node_modules` of course but then I copy them into `/wwwroot/lib` for deployment.

So in my TS files I presumably need this line:

```
import * as moment from "../lib/moment/moment.js";
```

But that's not right for TypeScript at design time.

Annoyingly, by setting `tsconfig.json:baseUrl` to `./wwwroot/` I can get the TS compiler/editor to recognise `lib/moment/moment.js` but Chrome doesn't see that as relative.

More annoyingly is that when I try and simply fix the situation as I type `./lib/` into the editor, the TS compiler seems to understand the path I'm trying to enter and "helpfully" removes the leading `./` making it useless for Chrome!

It's literally as if Chrome wants relative paths to start one way and TS wants it another way!

It's completely maddening! Hayalp!

Also, not sure how to tell which version of TS VS is using, or how to update it or anything.

Comment: The officially proposed solution for this is [import maps](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps), when it's ready you can use non-relative imports to refer to 'external' modules in `node_modules` when compiling, and then have import map to tell the browser where to find them. Currently, everyone is just using some kind of bundler like webpack after compilation.

Comment: Ah thanks, and there was me hoping I was just being dumb. I'll look into using `gulp-replace` and just rewrite the paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an NPM package called **gulp-replace** to fix the paths during the TS compile task, like so.

```
// gulpfile.js
const ts = require("gulp-typescript");
const tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");
const replace = require("gulp-replace");


function compileTypescript() {
    return tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsProject())        
        .js.pipe(replace('from "lib', 'from "../lib'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/js"));
}
gulp.task(compileTypescript);
```